# How to use a large number in Java like 300 decimal digits or more

Tags: java

I declared a long in Java code and it only take 19 decimal digits. I need a data type that takes over 300 decimal digits.

Comment: In the future, mark this as java. javascript and java are not the same.

Comment: And also, what is this for? You might be able to use a string, but tough to say without more info

Comment: *how to use large number in java like 300 decimal digit or more?* - What will you use it for?

Comment: Using a string to represent large numbers is a popular approach in any programming languages. But you may need to implement the operations you may need for your new string number class. Such as add, subtract, or etc as needed.

Comment: Perhaps [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Comment: @goatofanerd I need decimal values because i will use it to RSA algorithm program

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash RSA algorithm program

Comment: @BasilBourque BigDecimal is not big enough it's like 80 digit

Comment: @AmrAlasmer - BigDecimal can cope with numbers with *billions* of digits ... if you have enough RAM.

Comment: But if you are trying to implement RSA, you probably want `BigInteger`.   Because RSA is defined in terms of integers rather than "decimal values". Anyway, look at the javadocs and the duplink.

Answer (score 0):

There is no primitive type that supports a number that long.

What you are searching for is most likely a [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) object. Calculations are done through the methods shown in the API.

As another user said, Javascript and Java are two different languages, please use the correct tag.